# Pass parameter as bytes32 to Solidity Smart Contract

Tags: go, ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I am using [this Ethereum Go Client](https://github.com/regcostajr/go-web3) and trying to pass a string / bytes32 to Solidity.

The function in the smart contract is very simple (for testing now):

```
  function vote(bytes32 id) {
    //id has the value 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  }
```

calling

```
hash, err := contract.Send(transaction, "vote", "myString")
```

will result in `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

for the bytes32 param id...

How would I have to pass in the parameter to my Smart Contract from Go so that solidity will have the correct value?

Alternatively I just need to pass a unique identifier for that string that I can easily create in Golang from the string...

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not reproducible since the library you are using is no longer available; it has been deleted by its owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of the package told me that the reason for this is this issue:

https://web.archive.org/web/20201226194418/https://github.com/regcostajr/go-web3/issues/31

> **[regcostajr](https://github.com/regcostajr)** commented on [June 6, 2018](https://web.archive.org/web/20201226194418/https://github.com/regcostajr/go-web3/issues/31#issuecomment-394944032):
> Hi **[@jeffprestes](https://github.com/jeffprestes)**, thanks for the issue, the arguments encode in the contract struct appears to be completely wrong, we need to re-implement this based on the solidity docs: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

He is trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to encode it

```
types.ComplexString("myString")
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a `bytes32` for solidity all you have to do is create a fixed length byte array in Go and copy the string the value to it.

```
value := [32]byte{}
copy(key[:], []byte("hello"))
```

Then you may pass the value to the smart contract function:

```
hash, err := contract.Send(transaction, "vote", value)
```